# API for C/C++ programs. Which technique?

Tags: c++, c, api

Please, could you explain, which technique is common for developing API for C/C++ programs?
One example is sockets. And what else?

Thanks...

Comment: If you are asking how to develop a library/tool which provides an API, there are lots of open-source examples in GNU, Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the APIs standardised by the [Khronos Group](http://www.khronos.org/). They have a well-established convention of defining library interfaces in a concise way.

No, they probably don't hold the Guiness record for "Most convenient API", but they indeed could have one for "Most consistent API stanard", "Best legacy API deprecation model" or something of those sorts.

One example of such API is the [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/)'s.

Answer (score 0):

Don't develop your own system API. There's [plenty of documentation](http://www.unix.org/online.html) on them already.